# IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE for JVM

Tags: java, jvm, 32bit-64bit, heap-memory, wow64

Can I apply IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE to a 32 bit JVM in 64 bit windows so that JVM can avail 3-4 GB of memory? If yes, where should we add those parameters ?